# Re-boot Error Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, crash

Acer laptop with Windows 7 is giving error on boot that says it has encountered an unexpected error and needs to restart, and it does this in an endless reboot-loop.

Looking online I'm seeing lots of suggestions to reset my BIOS, but pressing F2 on boot asks me for a password and does not accept the password I give it.

If I press F10 (system recovery) instead and select any of those options, I get a disk.sys error and the system stops.

I've also pulled the battery and let the laptop sit for a day like this, but that makes no difference.

I don't have a boot or physical recovery disk.

Not even Checkdisk will run.

The only thing I can think of that might have started this is my 2yr old pressing random keys just before the initial crash.

This laptop has all my son's pictures and the drive I don't have another backup of these.

Comment: This won't help you fix your system, but you could download an Ubuntu live-cd, burn it to a dvd, run it in try mode, and then use it to copy your baby photos off the computer; make sure to run it in try mode though, don't install.

Comment: What do you mean when you hit F2 the password is wrong, your BIOS is locked with a password? So you can't enter BIOS?

Comment: That's correct. Yet it recognizes my password for F10.

Comment: There may be two different passwords in BIOS, one admin password for F2, and one user password for F10.

Comment: Yes I had two and neither worked and it wasn't caps locked either. Battery to hard drive has worked, its running as a first time use but its running again. Thank you so much everyone, I got my pictures back running that test progra and now don't need to buy a new lappy

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate battary holding the BIOS-settings, so it is not enough to just remove the main battery of the laptop. See if the following article helps you to clear the BIOS password.

http://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/manually-reset-bios-password-acer-18989.html

Comment: Awesome thank you, will this cause a loss of data ie my photos? But thank you, that's something I have not tried

Comment: If you don't break pins or cable of the hard disk while trying to remove the little battery, it is very unlikely that you will damage the hard disk by resetting BIOS.

Comment: Well I didn't actually take the battery out, just disconnected the led after pulling hard drive, computer got further along than before but still gets to one point and restarts. F2 still refuses to let me in, maybe I pulled wrong cable. I'll try again tonight.